# I want to authenticate users on my OpenEDX using auth0

Tags: oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, auth0, edx, openedx

I want to authenticate users on my OpenEDX using auth0.

[This](http://edx.readthedocs.io/projects/edx-installing-configuring-and-running/en/latest/configuration/tpa/tpa_integrate_open/tpa_oauth.html) documentation shows how to configure openEDX 0Auth2 with google, facebook, LinkedIn and Microsoft,but i would like to use auth0.

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box openedx supports what you see in that documentation file. Internally, it uses python-social-auth, which also does not support auth0.

If you definitely want to authenticate using auth0, you would have to fork and modify the source to support it yourself.